# Configuration Framework suggestions

Tags: spring, configuration, configuration-management

We are starting to work on a spring based web application (to run on 20 JVM's). The web application runs on different on Environments (say Dev, QA, test, Stress, Production).

We are looking into designing a configuration framework for the application with the below design goals...

**Design Goals for the configuration Framework**

1. Support an inheritance model :
           If a config property is static, it should be able to be defined globally, and inherited to all environments.  Environments should have the ability to override the value of an inherited property.
2. Elimination of redundancy :
            Should only have to look in one location to view, modify, and add config properties.   This should reduce the risk of missing a file when adding or modifying properties.
3. Ability to administer and maintain properties at runtime.
             Should be able to change a property in one-to-many JVMs in memory with ease, with the option to persist that change when the JVM is restarted.
4. Ability to debug.
             In order to determine current state of functional switches, etc, you should be able to easily dump properties out of memory (one-to-many properties).
5. Decrease the likelihood that different INT, QA, STRESS environments are out of sync and difficult to deploy to and maintain.
6. Support ease of the development, as well as the deployment process up through production.  This change should not negatively impact a local developer’s ability to be effective at developing.  To the contrary, it should make it easier.

Any Suggestions/Recommendations for achieving this kind of configuration framework in Spring?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of requirements there, and I don't have an answer for all of them, but I recommend the applications externalize as much of their runtime configuration parameters as possible.  I like to use property substitution in my bean files, with the values loaded from a well known location out on the file system.  In a production environment that location should be locked down so that only an admin or the app can read/write that location.

So in your development environment, you'd have things specific to a developer's needs (like local database credentials, etc).  Same thing for QA and production.  You build the app once (typically done by your build box/continuous integration server), and it just loads in its configuration for the environment it's been deployed to.  This separates all specifics from the codebase, which is nice for keeping sensitive information like passwords and encryption keys locked in a safe place.

If you aren't already familiar with using Spring to perform property substitution, look here:

[PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeff Hall's answer, but you might also want to read the documentation for the [`PropertyOverrideConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.html) class.

If the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` classes do not suit your needs, then you might want to consider the following two-step modification/enhancement of Jeff Hall's answer.

Step 1. My [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org) (pronounced "config 4 star") configuration-file parser addresses almost all of your stated requirements, except that it is not integrated into Spring. I suggest you read Chapters 2 and 3 of the "Config4* getting Started Guide" to decide if Config4* might be useful for your project. *If* you decide it might be useful, then...

Step 2. Make a copy of the source code of the Spring `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class, and modify it to obtain *name=value* pairs from a Config4* file instead of a properties file.

The potential benefit of that two-step suggestion is that you would not need to maintain separate properties files for each of your INT/QA/STRESS environments and/or for each of your 20 JVMs. Instead, the "adaptable configuration" capabilities of Config4* will enable you to put the runtime configuration values for *all* those environments and JVMs into a single configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest treating this not as a software development effort (Spring or otherwise) but more like a configuration management effort.

What we do to achieve most of these requirements is distinguish config that remains constant across environments from config that can potentially vary. For example, lots of your app wiring will remain constant, whereas passwords, web service URLs and so forth will vary. (Note that sometimes app wiring will change too. E.g. maybe on your local dev box you use local authentication but in other environments you use CAS.)

Then make sure that the config that's constant is just part of the app itself (i.e. packaged in the WAR or EAR), and the config that varies is externalized.

Where to externalize it? Set up a version control repository (a config repo) using your favorite version control tool, and then create folders for your various environments. Put the environment-specific config in the appropriate folder and then set your deployment scripts up to source the right config from the right folder.

This scheme is pretty nice. You get central management of config, which helps to control drift, and also provides for auditability, rollback, diagnostic support, etc. Branch the config just as you would branch source code.

Regarding Spring specifically, 3.1 will include support for something called profiles, which allows you to tailor configuration to specific environments I think. I haven't looked at it yet but that's what I remember hearing at SpringOne 2GX.

Comment: I don't understand how your answer addresses the question that was asked. In particular, I agree it is good to separate and externalize "changeable" config from "wiring" config is fine, but how do you suggest that the changeable config and wiring config eventually be used together? Do you agree with Jeff's suggestion of using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`? Or do you suggest a different approach?

Comment: I agree that PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is a useful tool here, and certainly we use it as part of the implementation of what I just described, but it is just a piece of a much larger approach to hit the requirements mentioned (other than the runtime one, which is an additional layer on top). [more]

Comment: To use the configs together, set the container up so that it adds an extra classpath, and copy the variable config to the extra classpath as part of the deployment. So the environment.properties file, e.g., would be copied there, and then picked up by the applicationContext.xml using a PPC. But you can also put other non-Spring config there as well, such as log4j.xml, which often varies by environment (e.g. debug on in dev and functional test but off in system test and prod). This approach helps with config drift because config is centrally managed and pushed anew with each deployment.